# Dropwizard - Bound mismatch: not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am kickstarting dropwizard example application where I am implementing HelloWorldService. Below are the classes I have.

But I am getting error

> Bound mismatch: The type TaskManagerConfiguration is not a valid
>   substitute for the bounded parameter  of the
>   type Application

in TaskManagerApplication.java and in HelloWorldService.java classes.

Can anyone help me on this?

TaskManagerConfiguration.java

```
package com.nagra.taskManager.config;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.*;

public class TaskManagerConfiguration extends Configuration {

   @NotEmpty
   @JsonProperty
   private String template;

   @NotEmpty
   @JsonProperty
   private String defaultName = "Stranger";

   public String getTemplate() {
       return template;
   }

   public String getDefaultName() {
       return defaultName;
   }
}
```

HelloWorldService.java

```
package com.nagra.taskManager.resources.service;

import com.nagra.taskManager.TaskManagerApplication;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.Service;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment;

public class HelloWorldService extends Service<TaskManagerApplication> {

   @Override
   public void initialize(Bootstrap<TaskManagerApplication> arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void run(TaskManagerApplication arg0, Environment arg1)
        throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

}
```

and TaskManagerApplication.java

```
package com.nagra.taskManager;

import com.nagra.taskManager.config.TaskManagerConfiguration;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

public class TaskManagerApplication extends Application<TaskManagerConfiguration> {

   public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
       new TaskManagerApplication().run(args);
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return "TaskManager";
   }

   @Override
   public void initialize(final Bootstrap<TaskManagerConfiguration> bootstrap) {
       // TODO: application initialization
   }

   @Override
   public void run(final TaskManagerConfiguration configuration,
                final Environment environment) {
       // TODO: implement application
   }

}
```

Comment: which `dropwizard` version you are using ?

Comment: Probably instead of `import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration;` in your `TaskManagerConfiguration`, use `import io.dropwizard.Configuration;`

Comment: I am using 1.0.5 version. Yes, using import io.dropwizard.Configuration in TaskManagerConfiguration has solved problem in TaskManagerConfiguration, Thanks. But the problem still exists in HelloWorldService.java class...

Comment: why do you want to use `HelloWordlService`? In terms how is that different from `TaskManagerApplication` ?

Answer (score 0):

Few things -

1. Ensuring the `Configuration` class is imported from `io.dropwizard.Configuration` and not the currently used `com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration; in your TaskManagerConfiguration.java.
2. If you go through the release [notes from `dropwizard`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/about/release-notes.rst#v070-apr-04-2014) - 
   The `com.yammer.dropwizard.Service` was used in the version `0.6.2` and prior of `dropwizard` and this has been moved to `import io.dropwizard.Application;`. So currently your `TaskManagerApplication` can be used as the main class for this application to run.